# How can I stop Heroku Dyno that is running a Rails task through Heroku Scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, dyno

[Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) uses a One-off Dyno to run the scheduled task. That dyno doesn't appear in Heroku Dashboard, but it's there. How can I restart it, or temporarily stop it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have the command line tools installed, `heroku ps` will list all the running processes, and you can use `ps:kill` or `ps:restart` to manage any of them.

`heroku help ps` will give you more details.

Answer (score 17):

To **stop a scheduled task**, find its ID with:

```
heroku ps

=== scheduler (Free): bundle exec rake myraketask (1)
scheduler.7114: up 2019/02/24 14:50:36 +1100 (~ 24m ago)

=== web (Free): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: up 2019/02/24 14:58:53 +1100 (~ 16m ago)
```

In the above, `scheduler.7114` is the scheduled task ID.

Stop it with:

```
heroku stop scheduler.7114
```

#### Other useful notes

If you need to restart it:

```sh
heroku restart scheduler.7114
```

Or if you need to kill it (e.g. if you see a [R16 -Detached](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r16-detached) error):

```sh
heroku kill scheduler.7114
```

- Note the [difference between `kill` and `stop`](https://superuser.com/questions/756999/whats-the-difference-between-docker-stop-and-docker-kill) is that stop will stop it gracefully, whereas kill will not

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to restart or stop. There are no dynos on Heroku dashboard, but you can find your scheduler in Heroku Scheduler dashboard.

You can set your schedulling tasks with running time you want and dyno plan.

When the time you set come, heroku scheduler dyno is started. After finishing the work, dyno is killed.

If you want to run manually, just call `heroku run rake xxxx` command.

Comment: No, I asked regarding how to end a schedule process that was already running, and I can't wait it to stop automatically.