# One-off dyno created by the heroku scheduler never dies (never kills itself, suicide...)

Tags: node.js, heroku

I use the [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) add-on to do a daily database scan and it works like a charm, yay

But it never kills itself. When I run `heroku ps -a mysuperapp` I can see that the dyno is still up even though its job has been completed a few hours ago.

That is not too surprising since nothing in my code tells the dyno "I'm done". But I don't see any doc explaining how to say "I'm done".

[This one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38898785/5941620) suggests that

> After finishing the work, dyno is killed

automagically, but that doesn't seem to happen in my case.

---

## TLDR;

How can I notify the one-off dyno created by heroku scheduler that its job is done and it can kill itself?

Comment: What command is your one-off dyno running? Does it exit, ideally with a 0 status?

Comment: Hey Chris, the command I use to get the dyno running is `$ node workers/dbscan` (at the root of the project there is a `workers` folder, with a `dbscan.js` file inside)
It does not exit with any status as far as I know.

Comment: If you run `node workers/dbscan` on your local machine, does the command finish, or does it run forvever? (If it exits it exits with an exit code.)

Comment: Well it does seem to exit in the sense that after the expected console.log()s are printed the terminal is ready for a new command. But I don't see no exit code anywhere. I tried adding `process.exit()` in order to see an exit code, but I must be looking at the wrong place... should it be printed in the terminal?

Comment: Exit codes aren't printed, but after the command finishes the code may be stored in a variable. For example, in bash you can run `echo $?` right after the command finishes to see the exit code. It sounds like the command _isn't_ finishing on Heroku. What does it do? Is there anything that might take a long time, go into an infinite loop, etc.? What happens if you run it interactively on Heroku, e.g. via `heroku run node workers/dbscan`?

Comment: Wow! Ok, not there yet, but you're being very helpful.
The `echo $?` works great, it does end with exit code 0 locally. However, when running it on heroku, it just sort of hangs there (even after adding `process.exit()` in the final `.then()`) The db scan does take a long time in production (around 30 minutes), but it does not seem to get stuck in an infinite loop since it gets to the final `.then()`(and there is a `.catch()`)

Comment: Maybe something as small as the database connection remaining active keeps the dyno alive? I do use a cursor, so maybe that needs to be closed. I'll look into those.

Comment: It could be. The one-off dyno is still running because the command didn't finish. If we can figure out why the command isn't finishing we should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: So it was the database connection! Thanks for your insights Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a one-off dyno never kills itself it's most probably because something is still active or never finishes or waits for a response.

In my case it was the database connection, adding `mongoose.disconnect()` solved the problem.

(Thanks to @Chris for getting me on the right track.)